# back button in jquery mobile without url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to have a back button without setting the url where you want to go?

I mean, I have a webpage in which I have a parameter in the url (www.page.com/?parameter). Inside this page I have a link to an external page. In the second page I want to have a button to go back to the first one having the same parameter (this parameter can change, because it is a unique identifier from each user).

So I want to have something like this:

```
<a href="previousPage" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
```

For returning to the previous page (But I don't know how to add the parameter to that url. Now I do it by pressing back key in my keyboard or return in browser. I want to do it in code.

If it is not possible, and there is a way to add the parameter, I can try to pass it to the new page and set in the button.

Comment: You could also use my [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which adds the ability for jquery mobile pages to accept URL parameters (and maintains them in the URL so that explicit URL navigation works). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try tomorrow morning and I will vote and aprove the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `document.referrer`